# Continue execution of services in background while using app Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-asynctask, background-process

I have some data to insert in database when user login mobile app. As well as I have some other services calls too, which makes my app login worst.
So here I want to know that how can I login immediately & continue execution of other data services in background.

However I am making `async` call which is doesn't seem to work.
The service calls I am making is it running in background? or I can make it more batter

```
private async Task InsertPushKeys()
{       
    foreach (var item in SISConst.Mychildren)
    {
        pushInfo.OrganizationId = Convert.ToInt64(item.OrganizationID);
        pushInfo.OsType = "Android";
        pushInfo.ServerkeyPush = SISConst.LmgKey;
        var ignore = await logDAL.InsertPushInfo(pushInfo);
    }
}
```

Below line executing the service.

```
var ignore = await logDAL.InsertPushInfo(pushInfo);
```

**Edit 1:**  These service I am calling inside login button in the same order

```
_btnSignUp.Click += async (s, e) =>
                    {
var loggedInUser = await uLogin.UserLogin(_inputName.Text.Trim(), _inputPassword.Text);
Task.Run(async () => { mychildList = await uLogin.BindMychildrenGridData(result.UserID); }).Wait(); 
await DeletePushKeys(loggedInUser.UserID);
InsertPushKeys();
                    };
```

Comment: try remove `await`  and `var ignore`
just call `logDAL.InsertPushInfo(pushInfo);`

Comment: I am not sure, I listen using `await` it makes execution continue.

Comment: await makes execution synchronous because its waits for execution completion and return value.

Comment: [Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index) 2nd paragraph _Async improves responsiveness_

Comment: Yep async is usual way to create web calls no doubt in that, but using `await` is an different approach it will wait anyway. it similar to call `get()` method in AsyncTask.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()

Comment: this lib may help you: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit

Comment: Ho do you call `InsertPushKeys`?

Comment: @Cheesebaron- I have updated my question please look at Edit 1. However I am calling this method Inside login button click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your services inside `Task.Run` without using await keyword. Await is holding control until it complete total execution. It might give warning for you that use await keyword but you can ignore it.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{       
     InsertPushKeys();
});
```

& don't try using `.Wait()`(until you need it) at the end of method it is holding your execution.

Answer (score 2):

Android provides JobService Class where you can schedule JobService from JobScheduler Class. JobScheduler runs the service in the background and you can go ahead with logging in.
 You can find one Xamarin example in here:
https://blog.xamarin.com/replacing-services-jobs-android-oreo-8-0/

Create a JobService class and add your InsertPushKeys code inside OnStartJob function.
Make sure to start it on New thread.

```
OnStartJob(JobParameters parameters){
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           await InsertPushKeys();
       }
   }).start();
}
```

Now Build the Job using JobInfo Class as shown in above link:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyJobService.class);
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(12, componentName)
       .setRequiresCharging(true)
   .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
   .build();
```

At last, you can schedule your job and it will get executed by android.

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
   Console.WriteLine(TAG, "Job scheduled!");
} else {
   Console.WriteLine(TAG, "Job not scheduled");
}
```

Make sure to run the task on a different thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to run services just in bg, not foreground or scheduled them.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for. Services are a construct provided by the Android framework to do exactly what you need. For more info, check -

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

**TLDR** : Put your API calls inside the service's `onCreate()`, and `return START_STICKY` from its `onStartCommand()`. Do not forget to call `startService()` on an instance of the service.